# How to obtain progress feedback on long running async API calls in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

We make several long-running, async, API calls using the Jsonclient to a ServiceStack host.  These calls perform a number of closely linked tasks.  I would like to obtain some feedback as to the current progress.

I can easily report back at which step the call failed, but I would like to provide more feedback to the user on when each stage completes.

It is not practical or even desired, to make individual calls to the API Host for each step.

We could use our Rabbit Messaging infrastructure to report back statuses, but that seems wrong.

I can see there is some feedback on upload and download operations as to x of y bytes...  Perhaps there is a way we could hijack this, and send back stages 1 of 5, 2 of 5, etc.

How do other people provide feedback on long-running API calls when using ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a separate channel to communicate back any API updates which I'd use [Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) for with both server and client sending and listening to the same channel for progress events. If you send events with `NotifySession` only the current browser session will receive the updates.